# Prevent Duplicate Google form submissions which add to a google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a google form which reflects its submissions to a google sheet, is there anyway i can prevent a duplicate phone number to be added in the google sheet?

Comment: you cant, but you can have a formula to remove duplicates

Comment: i used data validation in google sheets, is there a way in google sheets that can remove duplicates automatically once a number is submitted

Comment: like being said, it could be done with formula or with a script. can you share a copy of your sheet with some fake numbers?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder) which fires on every form submit and somewhat the following script to do whatever you want.

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet1') //change sheet name
  var range = sheet.getRange("C").getValues(); // assuming mobile is 3rd field so C

  var res = e.response.formResponses.getItemResponses();
  var mobile = res[2].getResponse(); // if mobile is 3rd field res[2] (0 indexed)
  for(i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
    if(mobile==range[i][0]) // mobile number found, delete it if more than one found?
  }
```

You may also want to check out [this](https://github.com/AJax2012/google-form-validation) for help.